# Adding JList to JavaFX ScrollPane

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have been attempting to make a `ScrollPane` containing strings that can be selected and figured `JList` would be good to do this with.
I've been looking up how to implement `JList` into a `ScrollPane` but none of the methods work, this is because the guides have been using swing `ScrollPane` (`JScrollPane`).

Is it impossible to add `JList` to JavaFX `ScrollPane`? If so, what can I do instead? If not, how do I add it?

Comment: What's wrong with a [`ListView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/list-view.htm) component, which is written to be use with JavaFX?

Comment: @MadProgrammer oh, I didn't know that class existed. I'm relatively new to javafx. Thanks!!!

Comment: This whole question just screams "why?"  If you want to use JavaFX, then read the JavaFX based tutorials.  If you want to use Swing, then just use Swing.  Can it be done.  Maybe. Should you. Not unless you have absolutely no other choice, as, in this case, JavaFX has a "list" component

Comment: @MadProgrammer Will keep in mind.

Comment: The JavaFx tutorial on using [ListView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/list-view.htm#CEGGEDBF)

Comment: Sorry (for running from the room screaming), I'm kind of purest when it comes to these things.  There might be use-cases where this is useful, but it just seems to scream bad idea to me :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: don't bother.  Instead make use of the [`ListView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/list-view.htm) provided by the JavaFX API.

"If" you have no other choice, then you should have a look at [Embedding Swing Content in JavaFX Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/embed-swing.htm#BCGCDEBD), BUT, I'd do every thing you can to avoid it, because they use different look and feels which is just going to confuse every body :P (and spending the time to implement a look and feel for one or the other is a lot of work which be better spent finding a better solution - IMHO)